# How can EC2 Classic Resource Finder be executed in aws cloud shell

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I would like to check resources that I may have that are running with EC2-classic. I don't have AWS CLI installed on my machine and was seeing if anyone has any idea in terms of how to run the ec2 classic resource finder script in the AWS cloud shell. This way I don't have to do any configurations for credentials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Secondly if it isn't possible how do you run the script on local machine. Do I need to have AWS cli? The documentation for this script is not particularly clear to me. (https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder)

Comment: It's a python script using boto3, so no it doesn't need the AWS CLI.

Comment: That is what I thought but I guess I am a little confused within this script where I am suppose to input my credentials

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue and has a small application.

You can run the following line one AWS cloud shell

`` aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?VpcId==`null`]' ``

It will return all ec2 instances that you may be running without VPC id.

Comment: This only returns the Instances, but if you also use other EC2 Classic resources, like Elastic IP or Security Groups you are still in a mess after Aug 15